# Iterating through table in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a table with structures containing polygon structure, each containing a table with ~ 100 complex numbers.

```
initPoly1(T[0]);
     ...
initPoly4(T[3]);
```

What I am doing is interpolating each polygon with the other using dt(wich goes between 0..1 and when it reaches 1 it starts once again with 0), so I am using the procedure to do interpolation and show the result(morphing effect):

```
animer(T[indice], T[indice+1], dt);
```

What I am stuck is I want to create a cycle/interation, like so
T[0], T[1] ... T[1], T[2] ... T[2], T[3], and then **T[3], T[0]** and on and on.

Is there any way besides what I did using 2 variables x and y:

```
if(dt == 1.0)
{
    x++;
    t++;
    if(t==4)
    {
        t=0;
    }
    else if(x==4)
    {
        x=0;
    }
}
animer(T[x], T[t], dt);
```

Because it slows my program so much, that the animation looks disturbing(but it works), any idea to improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use sum MODULE

```
    if(dt == 1.0)
    {
      x = (x+1)%4;
      t= (t+1)%4;
    }
    animer(T[x], T[t], dt);
```

or more simple

```
if(dt == 1.0)
{
  x = (x+1)%4;
}
animer(T[x], T[(x+1)%4], dt);
```

Comment: the second one solution is stellar, I was trying to figure something like this, but in vain, now it works sleek and pretty well, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single variable and compute the other. The `if` is OK, but more conventionally one would use the `%` remainder operation. Re

> **”** it slows my program so much

… that is an incorrect analysis: it's something else that slows down your code.